# Tensorflow Installation in Ubuntu14.04

Tags: python, tensorflow

I install tensorflow on my Ubuntu14.04,and I installed it with Anaconda.I follow the official installation guide.After I installed it,when I ran this code step by step.It went wrong.

```
import tensorflow as tf
hello = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')
sess = tf.Session()
print(sess.run(hello))
```

When I run

```
sess = tf.Session()
```

It says:

```
2017-09-03 17:04:11.220320: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.1 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-09-03 17:04:11.220355: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-09-03 17:04:11.220363: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-09-03 17:04:11.220369: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-09-03 17:04:11.220374: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use FMA instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an actual "error". It is [informing you](https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/performance_guide#best_practices) that the computations could be faster if you have installed from source with support to the mentioned instructions, e.g., SSE4.1, SSE4.2, etc.

You can go ahead and use Tensorflow, though it will be not as fast as compiled from the sources.

If you want to install Tensorflow with those instructions enabled, you have to:

1. Install Bazel

Download it from one of their available [releases](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/releases), for example [0.5.2](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/releases/download/0.5.2/bazel-0.5.2-dist.zip).
Extract it, go into the directory and configure it: `bash ./compile.sh`.
Copy the executable to `/usr/local/bin`: `sudo cp ./output/bazel /usr/local/bin`

2. Install Tensorflow

Clone tensorflow: `git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow.git`
Go to the cloned directory to configure it: `./configure`

It will prompt you with several questions, bellow I have suggested the response to each of the questions, you can, of course, choose your own responses upon as you prefer:

```
Using python library path: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Do you wish to build TensorFlow with MKL support? [y/N] y
MKL support will be enabled for TensorFlow
Do you wish to download MKL LIB from the web? [Y/n] Y
Please specify optimization flags to use during compilation when bazel option "--config=opt" is specified [Default is -march=native]: 
Do you wish to use jemalloc as the malloc implementation? [Y/n] n
jemalloc disabled
Do you wish to build TensorFlow with Google Cloud Platform support? [y/N] N
No Google Cloud Platform support will be enabled for TensorFlow
Do you wish to build TensorFlow with Hadoop File System support? [y/N] N
No Hadoop File System support will be enabled for TensorFlow
Do you wish to build TensorFlow with the XLA just-in-time compiler (experimental)? [y/N] N
No XLA JIT support will be enabled for TensorFlow
Do you wish to build TensorFlow with VERBS support? [y/N] N
No VERBS support will be enabled for TensorFlow
Do you wish to build TensorFlow with OpenCL support? [y/N] N
No OpenCL support will be enabled for TensorFlow
Do you wish to build TensorFlow with CUDA support? [y/N] N
No CUDA support will be enabled for TensorFlow
```

3. The final build will be a pip package, to build it you have to describe which instructions you want (you know, those Tensorflow informed you are missing).

Build pip script: `bazel build -c opt --copt=-mavx --copt=-mavx2 --copt=-mfma --copt=-mfpmath=both --copt=-msse4.1 --copt=-msse4.2 -k //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package`

Build pip package: `bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/build_pip_package /tmp/tensorflow_pkg`

Install Tensorflow pip package you just built: `sudo pip install /tmp/tensorflow_pkg/tensorflow-1.2.1-cp27-cp27mu-linux_x86_64.whl`

Now next time you start up Tensorflow it will not complain anymore about missing instructions.